# Different behaviour of encodeURIComponent() in Firefox only

Tags: javascript, firefox, url-encoding, encodeuricomponent

I encode a filename and send it as a part of URL like `/rest/get?name=Filename.txt`. In JS link construction is as simple as

```
url = '/rest/get?name=' + window.encodeURIComponent(file.name);
```

It works good for simple cases but for hardcore testing I use a file named

```
你好abcABCæøåÆØÅäöüïëêîâéíáóúýñ½§!#¤%&()=`@£$€{[]}+´¨^~'-_,;.txt
```

After URI encoding I expect to get a link

```
/rest/get?name=%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BDabcABC%C3%A6%C3%B8%C3%A5%C3%86%C3%98%C3%85%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC%C3%AF%C3%AB%C3%AA%C3%AE%C3%A2%C3%A9%C3%AD%C3%A1%C3%B3%C3%BA%C3%BD%C3%B1%C2%BD%C2%A7%3F%3FabcABC%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD!%23%C2%A4%25%26()%3D%60%40%C2%A3%24%E2%82%AC%7B%5B%5D%7D%2B%C2%B4%C2%A8%5E~%27-_%2C%3B.txt
```

And I get it. The constructed link works ok in the latest versions of IE and Chrome but fails in Firefox. After some investigation I've found that in Firefox `encodeURIcomponent` works differently. Here's actual result in Firefox:

```
/rest/get?name=%3F%3FabcABC%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD!%23%EF%BF%BD%25%26%28%29%3D%60%40%EF%BF%BD%24%3F{[]}%2B%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD^~%27-_%2C%3B.txt
```

Visual comparison (Chrome link is on the left and Firefox link is on the right):

[image: Comparison]

I've also tried to copy and paste the valid link (constructed in Chrome) to Firefox and it works ok.

Why do I get different results?
I̶s̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶a̶ ̶b̶u̶g̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶`̶e̶n̶c̶o̶d̶e̶U̶R̶I̶c̶o̶m̶p̶o̶n̶e̶n̶t̶(̶)̶`̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶F̶i̶r̶e̶f̶o̶x̶?̶
Does Firefox use a different encoding in [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)?

**UPD.** I've found similar questions ([encodeURIComponent behaves differently in browsers for China as location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715912/encodeuricomponent-behaves-differently-in-browsers-for-china-as-location) [搜索] and
[encodeURIComponent difference with browsers and ä-ö-å characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242977/encodeuricomponent-difference-with-browsers-and-%C3%A4-%C3%B6-%C3%A5-characters) [äöå]), both without an answer.

**UPD.2** Further investigation has shown that the following characters are encoded differently and causing 'File not found' exception on server:

- 你好
- æøåÆØÅäöüïëêîâéíáóúýñ
- ½§¤
- £€

Comment: I'm going to guess that it is either that the FireFox font map is different, or that whatever FF uses for a JavaScript interpreter is out of whack.

Comment: `%3F` is `?`, so looks like it's not understanding the unicode correctly.

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes, you're right. But as you can see the other part of URL is encoded differently either and if I remove `你好` from the beginning it still fails.

Comment: Have you tried using the .escape() and .unescape() functions for URI encoding? https://jsfiddle.net/vx4e9mb7/

Comment: @naXa Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vx4e9mb7/1/

Comment: escape() is deprecated as of JavaScript 1.5 (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your problem is not the encodeURIComponent() method. It's the encoding of whatever constructs `file.name`. Extend your question. How is `file.name` initialized? Where do the chars come from?

Comment: A list of files with their names is received from server.

Comment: so, can you make sure (using JS debugger), that file.name, just before passed to encodeURIComponent(), contains proper chars (and not question marks)?

Comment: @naXa Indeed, try `encodeURIComponent("你好")` in the devtools console, it returns "%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD", just as you expect.

Answer (score -1):

encodeURIComponent() is a native function so Firefox is obviously using some different implementation under the covers.

If you are stuck, then just deliver your own javascript implementation of encodeURIComponent(), then you'll get the same results across browsers.  Here's a link how to get an open source copy of that:

[encodeURIComponent algorithm source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635661/encodeuricomponent-algorithm-source-code)